# How to print each element with root attribute of the node of an XML file in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to print each element(Reference) of root node "Identity" with the attribute value of "Identity".

For example:

I want to print

```
00002C8DGPDDTZ5D, S2513.268898, John S2613.269022, JOHN
```

in one line  then  for

```
000388MRUO7TRSBH, S2513.285402,Doe, S2613.285476Doe
```

in another and so on.

Please let me know if I am not making myself clear.

Thanks

The XML file

```
<Identity Identifier="00002C8DGPDDTZ5D" CDate="2013-02-07">
<References>
    <Reference>
        <Value>A^S2513.268898|B^JOHN</Value>
        <Traces/>
    </Reference>
    <Reference>
        <Value>A^S2613.269022|B^JOHN</Value>
        <Traces/>
    </Reference>
</References>
 <Identity Identifier="000388MRUO7TRSBH" CDate="2013-02-07">
<References>
    <Reference>
        <Value>A^S2513.285402|B^Doe</Value>
        <Traces/>
    </Reference>
    <Reference>
        <Value>A^S2613.285476|B^Doe</Value>
        <Traces/>
    </Reference>
</References>
```

Also,

I tried the following code.

```
 XmlNodeList OysterID = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Identity");  
     XmlNodeList Reference = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Value");
 for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)

                    s[j] = Reference[j].InnerText;
```

I want something similar. I want a for loop which will print each element of a root with the root attribute value. I am not able to think how I can get the root attribute value with each element.

Comment: You don't close identity. This is not well formed XML. Also what have you tried so far people aren't here to do your work for you ...

Comment: Dont worry about closing tag. For posting it to stackexchange I removed the closing tag "</Identity>"

Comment: Also,  I tried XmlNodeList OysterID = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Identity");
                XmlNodeList Reference = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Value");

Comment: I am very naive to XMl. Just trying to learn.

Comment: I can print every reference. But I want to print the reference with root attribute value.for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                 s[j] = Reference[j].InnerText;

Comment: Where do you close Identity I assume after </References>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

```
        foreach (XmlNode element in xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Identity"))
        {
            string output = element.Attributes[0].Value;
            foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in element.ChildNodes)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode reference in xmlNode.ChildNodes)
                {
                    output += reference.InnerText;
                }
            }
            //Output here should be onelined.. 
        }
```

The output will not be formatted exactly as you wanted, so some formatting is needed. But you will have it on one line :)

Comment: A `StringBuilder` can improve performances if there are many `References` elements (ie using `StringBuilder.append` instead of `String.+=`).

Comment: I was using XMLDocument to load the file.

Comment: XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(@"C:\ID.idty");
                XmlNodeList OysterID = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Identity");
                XmlNodeList Reference = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Value");

Comment: What class does "doc" belong?

Comment: It was an XDocument. Ive updated my post so it should work with XmlDocument instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        string xml = @"<Identity Identifier=""00002C8DGPDDTZ5D"" CDate=""2013-02-07"">      <References>        <Reference>             <Value>A^S2513.268898|B^JOHN</Value>            <Traces/>       </Reference>        <Reference>             <Value>A^S2613.269022|B^JOHN</Value>            <Traces/>       </Reference>    </References>   <Identity Identifier=""000388MRUO7TRSBH"" CDate=""2013-02-07"">     </Identity>     <References>        <Reference>             <Value>A^S2513.285402|B^Doe</Value>             <Traces/>       </Reference>        <Reference>             <Value>A^S2613.285476|B^Doe</Value>             <Traces/>       </Reference>    </References>  </Identity>    ";
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        IEnumerable<XElement> entries = xmlDoc.Descendants("Reference");
        foreach (XElement entry in entries) {
            string temp = entry.Value;
        }
```